# Why is the total of 0.35 + 9.7 resulting in 10.049999999999999 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an application which sums up different numbers and I found out that there was a strange number in the application which was not showing the total of two numbers. I figured out that it is Javascript which is responsible for this number.

Does anybody have an idea why this sum results in this unexpected number?

I typed it also in the Chrome console:

[image]

Comment: Read "what every programmer should know about floating point": google this out.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript -- it is not at all unexpected, but an inherent problem of dealing with binary floating point numbers: You can express e.g. 0.2 exactly in decimal, but not in binary.